# How can I get "Ctrl+Shift+Right/Left" to select/mark a word in Eclipse?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, java, eclipse, text-editing

I'm using Eclipse 2019-12 (Java) on Windows 10 and I cannot get <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> to select/mark a word as it do in every other program I use. The same is true for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>...

The General -> Keys settings in Preferences seems to be just fine.

[image]

Note:
Just pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> works just fine. It selects a character at a time, as it should. But as soon as I try to add <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> into the equation, the cursor just halts (instead of selecting a word) and doesn't move at all until I release <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research I found a solution to the problem and it turns out to be a bug in the Eclipse IDE / Welcome Screen.

If the Checkbox "Always show Welcome at start up" is checked, the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>/<kbd>←</kbd> doesn't work.

[image: Welcome Screen - Always show Welcome at start up]

Then to be able to select/mark a word in the Eclipse IDE with the help of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd>/<kbd>Left</kbd> you need to **uncheck the Checkbox** "Always show Welcome at start up" and **restart Eclipse**.

If you need to access the Eclipse Welcome Screen, you'll find it under Help -> Welcome.

[image: Eclipse -> Help -> Welcome]